# Android - How to create tabs on demand using existing layout?

Tags: android, tabs, android-tabhost

Compulsory background info: I'm building a tablet app for real estate agents to use when quoting homes and buildings. Since a home or an apartment can have any number of rooms, I thought it would be nice to build a tab-based solution that allowed for going room by room and creating one tab per room on demand.

I've been through several tab tutorials but all solutions I've found deal with a predefined number of tabs, and use the deprecated TabHost.

```
TabHost.TabSpec ourSpec = tabhost.newTabSpec("tag1");
ourSpec.setContent(new TabHost.TabContentFactory()
{

    @Override
    public View createTabContent(String tag)
    {
        // Put some GUI stuff here
        return null;
    }
});
```

Problem: I want to reuse an existing layout for the new tab, and somehow keep count of how many tabs have been created so far.

Comment: describe a bit more of your problem? are you trying to add tab widget in tabhost dynamically from your program? what have you tried and what are the problems are you facing

Comment: Well, yes, I'm trying to add new tabs dynamically, not simply defining them via XML files. They all should contain the same GUI elements. I can create the new tab alright, but I don't know how to tell it to use the same layout as the first tab.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After LOTS of research, finally managed to put together something workable.

Sankar Ganesh's [tutorial](http://sankarganesh-info-exchange.blogspot.com.ar/2011/04/adding-tabs-dynamically-in-android.html) was very useful.

MainActivity.java:

```
package com.example.workingdynamictabexample;

import android.app.TabActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TabHost;

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public class MainActivity extends TabActivity
{
    private TabHost tabHost;

    private int z = 0;

    private static final int
        ADD_TAB = Menu.FIRST + 11,
        DELETE_TAB = Menu.FIRST + 12;

    private String Test = null;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        this.tabHost = getTabHost();

        Intent newRoom = new Intent();

        newRoom.setClass(this, RoomActivity.class);

        Test = Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER;

        Log.d("Test", Test);

        tabHost.addTab(
                tabHost.newTabSpec("Main")
                        .setIndicator("New room")
                        .setContent(newRoom)
                        );
    }

    private void addTab()
    {
        Intent newRoom = new Intent();

        newRoom.setClass(this, RoomActivity.class);

        tabHost.addTab(
                tabHost.newTabSpec("NewRoomTab")
                        .setIndicator("New room")
                        .setContent(newRoom)
                );

        Log.d("z", Integer.toString(z));

        ++z;
    }

    // "Boss, we really cannot delete one a'dem tab gubbinz, so we hides 'em."
    private void deleteTab() 
    {
        int position = tabHost.getCurrentTab();
        Log.d("Position", Integer.toString(position));

        Log.d("Z val in delete()", Integer.toString(z));

        tabHost.getCurrentTabView().setVisibility(View.GONE);

        if (position > 0)
        {
            tabHost.setCurrentTab(position + 1);

            z -= 1;

            if (z < 0)
            {
                z = 0;
            }
        }
        else if (position == 0)
        {
            tabHost.setCurrentTab(position + 1);

            z = 0;
        }
        else if (position == z)
        {
            tabHost.setCurrentTab(z - 1);

            Log.d("Z value in final", "lol");
            Log.d("Pos", Integer.toString(position));
            Log.d("Z pos", Integer.toString(z));
        }       
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) 
    {
        menu.add(Menu.NONE, ADD_TAB, Menu.NONE, "New room")
            .setAlphabeticShortcut('a');

        return (super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu));
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)
    {
        switch (item.getItemId())
        {
        case ADD_TAB:
            addTab();

            return (true);

        case DELETE_TAB:
            deleteTab();

            return (true);
        }

        return (super.onOptionsItemSelected(item));
    }
}
```

RoomActivity.java:

```
package com.example.workingdynamictabexample;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;

public class RoomActivity extends Activity
{
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.tabhost);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) 
    {
        return (super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu));
    }
}
```

activity_main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:padding="5dp">

        <TabWidget
            android:id="@android:id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:tag="tabPane" />

            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent">                
            </FrameLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
</TabHost>
```

tabhost.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:padding="5dp">

        <TabWidget
            android:id="@android:id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:tag="tabPane" 
        />

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/tab_room"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent">

                 <Button
                     android:id="@+id/btnAddTab"
                     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                     android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                     android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                     android:onClick="addTab"
                     android:text="Add room" />

                 <TextView
                     android:id="@+id/lblType"
                     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                     android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                     android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                     android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                     android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
                     android:text="Room type:" />

                 <Spinner
                     android:id="@+id/spinnerType"
                     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                     android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/lblType"
                     android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                     android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/lblType" />

                 <TextView
                     android:id="@+id/lblWidthX"
                     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                     android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/lblType"
                     android:layout_below="@+id/lblType"
                     android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
                     android:text="Dimension 1:" />

                 <TextView
                     android:id="@+id/lblWidthY"
                     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                     android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/lblWidthX"
                     android:layout_below="@+id/lblWidthX"
                     android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
                     android:text="Dimension 2:" />

                 <EditText
                     android:id="@+id/txtWidthX"
                     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                     android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/lblWidthX"
                     android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/lblWidthX"
                     android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/txtWidthY"
                     android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                     android:ems="10" >

                     <requestFocus />
                 </EditText>

                 <EditText
                     android:id="@+id/txtWidthY"
                     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                     android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/lblWidthY"
                     android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/lblWidthY"
                     android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                     android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/lblWidthY"
                     android:ems="10" />

                 <TextView
                     android:id="@+id/lblFloors"
                     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                     android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/lblWidthY"
                     android:layout_below="@+id/txtWidthY"
                     android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
                     android:text="Floors:" />

                 <EditText
                     android:id="@+id/txtFloors"
                     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                     android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/lblFloors"
                     android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/lblFloors"
                     android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                     android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/lblFloors"
                     android:ems="10" />

            </RelativeLayout>

        </FrameLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</TabHost>
```

Answer (score 1):

for this I used following code

```
TabSpec fifthTabSpec = tabHost.newTabSpec("tid5");
addTab(fifthTabSpec , "",
        getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.icon), new Intent(
                A.this, B.class));
```

and here is the addTab method

```
private void addTab(TabSpec spec, String labelId, Drawable drawable,
            Intent intent) {

        View tabIndicator = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(
                R.layout.tab_indicator, getTabWidget(), false); // tab_indicator is a layout for the tab widget as i used custom icon and style

        ImageView icon = (ImageView) tabIndicator.findViewById(R.id.icon);
        icon.setImageDrawable(drawable);
        icon.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_CENTER);

        spec.setIndicator(tabIndicator);
        spec.setContent(intent);
        tabHost.addTab(spec);
    }
```

here is the tab_indicator

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="0dip"
android:layout_height="55dip"
android:layout_weight="1"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:weightSum="55" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/icon"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_weight="30"
    android:adjustViewBounds="false"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:background="@drawable/tab_icon_selector"  // tab_icon_selector is custom selector
    android:src="@drawable/icon" />
```

Hope you will find this helpful

Comment: Tried it out. Works, but I can't see any tab buttons anymore after that. I try clicking on where tabs are supposed to go and I get an IllegalStateException asking out if I forgot to call setup(LocalActivityManager activityGroup).

Comment: Solved that last issue (solution at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9409735/java-lang-illegalstateexception-at-tabhost-addtabspec) but I'm getting a funny behavior: the entire layout is being replicated and partially overwritten, once for each time I press the 'add tab' button...